# Evaluation Error when tidyverse is loaded after Hmisc

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, hmisc

I am using r 3.3.3, dplyr 0.7.4, and Hmisc 4.1-1. I noticed that the order I load packages effects whether or not a dplyr::summaries function wold work or not. I understand that loading packages in a different order would mask certain functions but I am using the package::function() syntax to avoid that issue. The exact issue revolves around labeled variables. I know that there has been issues in the past with tidyverse and variable labels but none seem to address why this particular situation is occurring.

First example that works - I load only Hmisc then dplyr and I am able to summaries the data-

```
#this works fine
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)

Hmisc::label(iris$Petal.Width) <- "Petal Width"

sumpct <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(med =median(Petal.Width),A40 = round(100*ecdf(Petal.Width)(.40),1),
            A50 =round(100*ecdf(Petal.Width)(.50),1),
            mns = mean(Petal.Width),
            lowermean = mean(Petal.Width)-sd(Petal.Width),
            lowermedian = median(Petal.Width) - sd(Petal.Width))
```

Second example below breaks. I start a new session and load tidyverse after Hmisc and still use the package::function() syntax but this throws the error :

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: `x` and
>   `labels` must be same type.

Second example:

```
###restart session 
#this example does not work

library(Hmisc)
library(tidyverse)


Hmisc::label(iris$Petal.Width) <- "Petal Width"

sumpct <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(med =median(Petal.Width),A40 = round(100*ecdf(Petal.Width)(.40),1),
                   A50 =round(100*ecdf(Petal.Width)(.50),1),
                   mns = mean(Petal.Width),
                   lowermean = mean(Petal.Width)-sd(Petal.Width),
                   lowermedian = median(Petal.Width) - sd(Petal.Width))
```

However, the third example does work where I just restart the session and load tidyverse before Hmisc

Third example:

```
###switch order of loading packages and this works

library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)


Hmisc::label(iris$Petal.Width) <- "Petal Width"

sumpct <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(med =median(Petal.Width),A40 = round(100*ecdf(Petal.Width)(.40),1),
                   A50 =round(100*ecdf(Petal.Width)(.50),1),
                   mns = mean(Petal.Width),
                   lowermean = mean(Petal.Width)-sd(Petal.Width),
                   lowermedian = median(Petal.Width) - sd(Petal.Width))
```

So my question is why does the order in which I load packages matter when I am using the package::function() syntax specifically with respect to labeled variables and tidyverse?

Update: session info below for the error:

```
sessionInfo()
```

> > R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) 
> >     Running under: Windows 7 x64 
> >       attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] bindrcpp_0.2    forcats_0.3.0
>   stringr_1.3.0   dplyr_0.7.4      [5] purrr_0.2.4     readr_1.1.1
>   tidyr_0.8.0     tibble_1.4.2     [9] tidyverse_1.2.1 Hmisc_4.1-1
>   ggplot2_2.2.1   Formula_1.2-2   [13] survival_2.41-3 lattice_0.20-35
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] reshape2_1.4.3
>   splines_3.3.3       haven_1.1.1          [4] colorspace_1.3-2
>   htmltools_0.3.6     base64enc_0.1-3      [7] rlang_0.2.0
>   pillar_1.2.1        foreign_0.8-69      [10] glue_1.2.0
>   RColorBrewer_1.1-2  readxl_1.0.0        [13] modelr_0.1.1
>   plyr_1.8.4          bindr_0.1.1         [16] cellranger_1.1.0
>   munsell_0.4.3       gtable_0.2.0        [19] rvest_0.3.2
>   htmlwidgets_1.0     psych_1.7.8         [22] latticeExtra_0.6-28
>   knitr_1.20          parallel_3.3.3      [25] htmlTable_1.11.2
>   broom_0.4.3         Rcpp_0.12.16        [28] acepack_1.4.1
>   scales_0.5.0        backports_1.1.2     [31] checkmate_1.8.5
>   jsonlite_1.5        gridExtra_2.3       [34] mnormt_1.5-5
>   hms_0.4.2           digest_0.6.15       [37] stringi_1.1.7
>   grid_3.3.3          cli_1.0.0           [40] tools_3.3.3
>   magrittr_1.5        lazyeval_0.2.1      [43] cluster_2.0.6
>   crayon_1.3.4        pkgconfig_2.0.1     [46] Matrix_1.2-12
>   xml2_1.2.0          data.table_1.10.4-3 [49] lubridate_1.7.3
>   assertthat_0.2.0    httr_1.3.1          [52] rstudioapi_0.7
>   R6_2.2.2            rpart_4.1-13        [55] nnet_7.3-12
>   nlme_3.1-131.1

Comment: I just tried this, and both the second and third options gave me the error. So perhaps it is to do with the combination of Hmisc and tidyverse, rather than the package order? Perplexing

Comment: Interesting I just tried the third example again and it worked, what versions are you using, and did you restart your session? Either way it is an interesting problem.

Comment: I currently have Hmisc 4.1-1, dplyr 0.74, tidyverse 1.2.1, R 3.4.3. I will try updating R and all other packages to see what happens, recommend you do the same and post your session info

Comment: Just added session info

Comment: Seems to be caused by both `haven` and `Hmisc` using a `labelled` S3 class and defining `[.labelled`. You use `Hmsic::label` to create a `labelled` variable, but when you try to subset it with `[` in any scenario, the `haven` version is called instead if you loaded `tidyverse` after `Hmisc`. You can see this with `getAnywhere("[.labelled")`.

Comment: Just to drill down on the issue, a minimal example would be to just do `head(iris)` after you've assigned the label to `iris$Petal.Width`.

Comment: And the final piece is, that because `haven` is listed as an Import in `tidyverse`, its namespace gets loaded when `tidyverse` is loaded. And if that happens _after_ the `Hmisc` namespace has been loaded, the `[.labelled` S3 method from `haven` will be found before the `Hmisc` one during S3 dispatch. Doesn't seem like there is any way around this, other than changes to either `haven` or `Hmsic`.

Comment: Great thank you for the response. If you submit it as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of [**haven** version 2.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/blob/master/NEWS.md#haven-200) this issue has been resolved, as the haven "labelled" class was renamed to `"haven_labelled"` to avoid conflicts with **Hmisc**.

---

**tl;dr:** Order matters.

For a more detailed answer, let's first reproduce the error:

```r
library(Hmisc)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.4.4
```

After removing elements piece by piece from the original `summarise` example,
I managed to reduce reproducing the error to just these lines of code:

```r
Hmisc::label(iris$Petal.Width) <- "Petal Width"
head(iris)
#> Error: `x` and `labels` must be same type
```

We can have a look at the traceback to see if we can locate a function that could be causing the error:

```r
traceback()
#> 8: stop("`x` and `labels` must be same type", call. = FALSE)
#> 7: labelled(NextMethod(), attr(x, "labels"))
#> 6: `[.labelled`(xj, i)
#> 5: xj[i]
#> 4: `[.data.frame`(x, seq_len(n), , drop = FALSE)
#> 3: x[seq_len(n), , drop = FALSE]
#> 2: head.data.frame(iris)
#> 1: head(iris)
```

The `[.labelled` call looks suspicious. Why is it even called?

```r
lapply(iris, class)
#> $Sepal.Length
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $Sepal.Width
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $Petal.Length
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $Petal.Width
#> [1] "labelled" "numeric" 
#> 
#> $Species
#> [1] "factor"
```

Ah, setting a label for `Petal.Width` with `Hmisc::label` also added the S3 class.
We can inspect where the method is defined with `getAnywhere`:

```r
getAnywhere("[.labelled")
#> 2 differing objects matching '[.labelled' were found
#> in the following places
#>   registered S3 method for [ from namespace haven
#>   namespace:Hmisc
#>   namespace:haven
#> Use [] to view one of them
```

Indeed, both `haven` and `Hmisc` define the method. And since `haven` is
loaded after `Hmisc`, its definition is found first, and thus gets used:

```r
getAnywhere("[.labelled")[1]
#> function (x, ...) 
#> {
#>     labelled(NextMethod(), attr(x, "labels"))
#> }
#> <environment: namespace:haven>
```

`haven` expects `labelled` objects to have a `labels` attribute, which
`Hmisc::label` doesn't create:

```r
attr(iris$Petal.Width, "labels")
#> NULL
```

And that's where the error comes from.

---

**But wait:** why is `haven` even loaded? It's not attached with `library(tidyverse)`.
Turns out, that `haven` is [listed as an imported package](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) in `tidyverse`,
which causes it to be loaded when the package is attached (see e.g.
[here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html)). And loading a package,
among other things, registers its S3 methods: which is where the conflict
comes from.

As it is, if you want to use both `Hmisc` and `tidyverse`, order matters.
To address the issue further would likely require source level changes in
the packages' use of the `labelled` S3 class.

Created on 2018-03-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Incredible answer and bug-digging ! Little question, wouldn't it be possible to manually override the method ? For a simple function I would write something like `\`[.labelled\` <- Hmisc::\`[.labelled\``, but it doesn't seems to apply here.

Comment: @DanChaltiel Good question, but I have to say I'm a bit out of my depth here. I think this goes to the details of how S3 method dispatch works (and I can't find a good reference with a quick search), but it seems that the gist of it is that methods in loaded packages are found before methods in the global environment. A hack-y workaround could be to override the method in the **haven**  namespace (but beware if you actually want to use the **haven** version at some point!). This should do the trick: `assignInNamespace("[.labelled", Hmisc:::"[.labelled", asNamespace("haven"))`.